# Lumisoft IMAP attachment saved 0 bytes

Tags: c#, imap, attachment, lumisoft

I am trying to save an attachment via IMAP protocol in .NET c#, using Lumisoft library. The problem is that the file is downloaded and can be saved, but it's filesize is 0B.

Attachment is fetched by `IMAP_Fetch_DataItem_Rfc822()`. Variable `mail` is message parsed from stream: `var mail = Mail_Message.ParseFromStream(stream);`

```
foreach (var att in mail.Attachments)
{
  if (att.ContentType.Type == "image")
  { 
    try
    {
      var fPath = Path.Combine(dirPath, att.ContentType.Param_Name);
      if (!File.Exists(fPath))
      {
        Stream data = ((MIME_b_SinglepartBase)att.Body).GetDataStream();

        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fPath))
        {
           LumiSoft.Net.Net_Utils.StreamCopy(data, fs, 4096);
        }  
     }
   Console.WriteLine("Storing image attachment into: " + fPath);

 ...
```

Comment: do you mean `LumiSoft.Net.Net_Utils.StreamCopy(data, fs, 4096);`? because you're writing to `ms` at the moment.

Comment: yes, I was try something with MemoryStream and forgot to rollback changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `Stream data`:

```
Stream data = ((MIME_b_SinglepartBase)att.Body).GetDataStream();
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fPath))
{
       LumiSoft.Net.Net_Utils.StreamCopy(data, fs, 4096);
}
data.Close(); // missing close
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Lumisoft parser did not decode attachment correctly.
Are you sure the attachment size after download is more that zero?

LumiSoft unfortunately is pretty buggy, you may consider using commercial alternative, 
here's my product: http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/

Comment: When I debugg I can see all metadata including picture size. Funny thing is, that this already worked in past. After one week of testing I was forced to move to MailSystem.NET library. This one it works, but is damn slow.